# Mockito mocking same named method with similar signatures

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a class, say `SimpleClass`, that has two functions with the same name and the same number of parameters but different parameter types. Now I assume mocking their return values should be as using two `when` statements with the appropriate matchers but instead when I attempt that I get the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at mocks.MockTest.whenMethodsHaveSimilarSignatures(MockTest.java:28)
>   -> at mocks.MockTest.whenMethodsHaveSimilarSignatures(MockTest.java:28)

Here's a sample of what I'm attempting:

```
public class SimpleClass {

    public boolean doWork(String value, String name) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean doWork(Integer value, String name) {
        return true;
    }
}



@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockTest {

    private SimpleClass thing;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        thing = new SimpleClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenMethodsHaveSimilarSignatures() {

        when(thing.doWork(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);
        when(thing.doWork(any(Integer.class), anyString())).thenReturn(false);

        assertThat(thing.doWork("one", "name")).isTrue();
        assertThat(thing.doWork(1, "name")).isFalse();
    }
}
```

While I'm not a wizard at Mockito I've been using it for a while and never encountered this issue. Thoughts? I'm using Mockito-Core v2.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `any(Object.class)` while stubbing overloaded methods because both `String` and `Integer` are child classes of `Object`, so specify the particular arguments during stubbing.You can also use `ArgumentMatchers`

```
when(thing.doWork(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
when(thing.doWork(ArgumentMatchers.any(Integer.class), anyString())).thenReturn(false);
```

And also you are not mocking the `SimpleClass`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockTest {

private SimpleClass thing = Mockito.mock(SimpleClass.Class);

@Before
public void setup() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  // need to enable these annotations programmatically
}

@Test
public void whenMethodsHaveSimilarSignatures() {

    when(thing.doWork(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    when(thing.doWork(any(Integer.class), anyString())).thenReturn(false);

 //or

   when(thing.doWork(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
   when(thing.doWork(ArgumentMatchers.any(Integer.class), anyString())).thenReturn(false);

    assertThat(thing.doWork("one", "name")).isTrue();
    assertThat(thing.doWork(1, "name")).isFalse();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I actually tried a number of classes, I actually tried Integer.class too and same result. I've updated the post to reflect that to reduce confusion.

Comment: Good catch on the not mocking the object, clearly I need to step away from the keyboard. Interestingly enough though I upgraded the library to 2.27 and used your example and now I'm unable to mock that class at all getting an exception `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.salesforce.rtim.datatransfer.mocks.handlerMock.SimpleClass.`

Comment: downgrade it and try, that might me different issue or please upload error and stack trace in post @ars265

Comment: Downgrade seemed to work. I think there might have been an issue with a newer dependency.